# Can I use a 1" stem on a 1 & 1/8" steer tube?

Tags: stem, steerer

I have a Nitto Technomic stem that I'd like to use on a '92 trek 930 with the idea of converting it from a mountain bike to a poor man's expedition touring bike with drops.

I found this [shim](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/alloy-shim-to-fit-1-inch-222-mm-insert-quill-stem-to-1-1-8-inch-forks-prod430/?geoc=us) that would seem to do the job.

Has anyone tried this? Is it a bad idea? I can't think of any reason why, but that's why I'm throwing it out here.

Comment: If you're using a quill stem, you might want to look into getting a [quill stem adaptor](http://www.jensonusa.com/Dimension-Quill-Stem-Adaptor).  This would allow you to use a more modern stem which are available in many more lengths and angles than traditional quill stems.

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want to use a 1" quill stem for the ability to change the handlebar height while touring, road handlebar compatibility and aesthetic reasons.

Comment: In that case, they also make adjustable angle threadless stems. I had one before, and I didn't really like it, as it had some movement in it.  Maybe mine wasn't good quality.  Anyway,  I understand why you'd want to use a quill stem in this situation. Makes adjusting the height pretty easy.

Comment: Totally aware of those also. Not a big fan. They're heavy, ugly and have less height adjustment when compared to a long quill stem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the opposite (but drop bars before and after), and have a quill stem adaptor to use a non-quill stem with a threaded headset. My fork is 1", but the adaptor came with a similar shim for 1 1/8" steerers. I've also used quill stems with threadless headsets, but only with matching sizes.

I don't see any reason the product you link to won't do the job it's designed for though.

To replace a non-quill stem with a quill stem you'll need something like 
http://problemsolversbike.com/products/locking_headset_spacers, cf. "Threadless Without Spacers" at http://sheldonbrown.com/handsup.html#threadless

I assume you are replacing a 1 1/8" quill stem on your trek though?

Comment: That's right, it's a 1 1/8" threaded headset/quill stem currently on the trek.